# Sharepoint list, calculated column, IF condition, syntax error

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I would like to ask for help here.

I have a Sharepoint list with some marketing numbers, in one column, I have monthly summary of some numbers.

This is my formula, I don't know what the issue is:

```
=IF([column1]<6950000,"0%",
  IF(AND([column1]>="6950000,[column1]<7050000),"40%",
    IF(AND([column1]>=7050000,[column1]<7150000),"50%",
      IF(AND([column1]>=7150000, [column1]<7200000),"60%",
        IF(AND([column1]>=7200000, [column1]<7250000),"70%",
          IF(AND([column1]>=7250000, [column1]<7350000),"80%",
            IF(AND([column1]>=7350000, [column1]<7500000),"90%",
              IF([column1]>=7500000,"100%",
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I need to compare these numbers with the ones in code. If the value corresponds to it, I need it to show how much % is that ...

Glad for any advice

Comment: Is this a typo in your question? `>="6950000,` I mean the quote in front of the number.

Comment: What is the column/data type of `column1`, number or single line of text?

Comment: Test with Ganesh Sanap's calculated formula and it works well. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If your `column1` is of type "Number", use formula like below for your calculated column:

```
=IF([column1]<6950000,"0%",IF(AND([column1]>=6950000,[column1]<7050000),"40%",IF(AND([column1]>=7050000,[column1]<7150000),"50%",IF(AND([column1]>=7150000, [column1]<7200000),"60%",IF(AND([column1]>=7200000, [column1]<7250000),"70%",IF(AND([column1]>=7250000, [column1]<7350000),"80%",IF(AND([column1]>=7350000, [column1]<7500000),"90%",IF([column1]>=7500000,"100%",""))))))))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.